# regulate browser memory consumption

Tags: windows-7, firefox, memory, 64-bit, batch-file

I play a browser-based game that I would like to be able to keep running 24/7 if possible. The problem is that the more the page is refreshed, and the longer the game kept running, the more memory the browser eats up.

My question would be this:

- Is there a way to limit the amount of memory and CPU usage used by the browser?

  If not

  - would it be viable to write a batch file that would close the browser, wait until the process ends and then restart the browser to the page in question? If so, can anyone point me to a resource that describes how to do this?

Comment: This is the typical behavior of a browser.  It sounds like you need more system memory if browser based games are tasking your system

Comment: How are you measuring how much memory the browser "eats up"? Are you measuring physical memory or virtual memory?

Comment: You can try to free up some memory by visiting `about:memory` page in Firefox. If it helps you may be lucky enough to find an addon that does it auto-periodically.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sometimes when I get on after leaving the game running overnight, I'll open the Task Manager and under the Private Working Set Memory it will show Pale Moon at around 800,000 k, and my CPU usage is pushing 100%. Someone once told me that I could manage things with the Paging File size, but I thought that was just Virtual Memory...?

Comment: Private working set is physical memory that is, at least temporarily, assigned specifically to that process. Amazingly, 800MB is not out of line for a modern browser doing normal stuff.

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess no. If your operating system refuses to give memory to the browser process, it will fail certainly.
2. You could use Windows's Task Scheduler and setup a periodic task for killing and starting the browser. For killing a process by name from command line, you could use [Daphne](http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php)